# Return Type Covariant

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, iterator

Why did `invalid covariant return type` error occur?

I am trying to implement a template base iterator and a derived iterator.

Code:

```
template <typename T>
class BaseClassA{
    public:
        virtual bool operator!=(const BaseClassA<T> & A) const {}
        virtual BaseClassA<T> operator++(T){}
} ;
template <typename T>
class DerivedClassA: public BaseClassA<T>{
    private:
        T* p;
    public:
        DerivedClassA<T>  operator++(T){
            DerivedClassA<T> tmp(*this);
            ++p;
            return tmp;
        }
        bool operator!=(const DerivedClassA<T> & A) const {
            return (A.p != p);
        } 
} ;

template <typename T>
class BaseClassB{
    private:
        BaseClassA<T> beginIter;
        BaseClassA<T> endIter;
    public:
        virtual BaseClassA<T> begin(void){}
        virtual BaseClassA<T> end(void){}
} ;

template <typename T>
class DerivedClassB{
    private:
        DerivedClassA<T> beginIter;
        DerivedClassA<T> endIter;
    public:
        DerivedClassA<T> begin(void){ return beginIter; }
        DerivedClassA<T> end(void){ return endIter; }
} ;

int main(void){
    DerivedClassB<int> B;
    B.begin() != B.end();
    ++B.begin();
}
```

Compiler Error (g++)

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'class DerivedClassA<int>':
test.cpp:35:26:   required from 'class DerivedClassB<int>'
test.cpp:43:24:   required from here
test.cpp:12:27: error: invalid covariant return type for 'DerivedClassA<T> DerivedClassA<T>::operator++(T) [with T = int]'
         DerivedClassA<T>  operator++(T){
                           ^
test.cpp:5:31: error:   overriding 'BaseClassA<T> BaseClassA<T>::operator++(T) [with T = int]'
         virtual BaseClassA<T> operator++(T){}
                               ^
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:45:5: error: no match for 'operator++' (operand type is 'DerivedClassA<int>')
     ++B.begin();
     ^
test.cpp:45:5: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:12:27: note: DerivedClassA<T> DerivedClassA<T>::operator++(T) [with T = int]
         DerivedClassA<T>  operator++(T){
                           ^
test.cpp:12:27: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: You don't want runtime checking of the validity of an equality comparision, really you don't.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the template typename T would solve that. But for now I just want to know why the covariant return type error comes up.

Comment: @Jason, see the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39558746/iterator-performance I adapted the code at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/

Comment: Two things, your asking error is because the return types for operator++ are different. Then in main, DerivedClassB has no operator++

Comment: @lakeweb: Do you mean that the operator++ in the base class return a baseclass and the operator++ in the derived class return the derived class? Does that mean using base class would not work?

Comment: My mistake, I looked too quickly. the second error stems from the first error. The types do not match. google 'invalid covariant return type' for several stackoverflow results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ built-in covariance applies to references and pointers in the C++ object model.

Now this is C++.  So if you don't like what C++ provides, you can write your own object model.

In your case you have iterators.  These iterators want to be value types (because that is what C++ wants in its libraries), and you want them to be polymorphic.

Polymorphic value types are not supported naively using the C++ object model.

Using [code like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534325/1774667) or [adobe poly](https://stlab.adobe.com/group__poly__related.html) or [boost type erasure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure.html) or [boost any_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/any_range.html) you can create a ducktype polymorphism system that supports value-type polymorphism.

Now your `BaseClassB<T>::begin` and `end` returns an `any_iterator<T>`.  Things that match the concept, including `DerivedClassA<T>`, can be stored and manipulated within it.  `BaseClassA<T>` becomes obsolete, as a type erasing iterator does not require a virtual base class for polymorphism.

`DerivedClassB<T>` also returns an `any_iterator<T>`.  If you want naked access to the real iterators of `DerivedClassB<T>` have a function called `get_naked_range()` that returns the naked iterators of `DerivedClassB<T>`, which can be used in contexts where you are absolutely certain the type is `DerivedClassB<T>`.  If you do so, also mark `begin` and `end` as `final`.

Note that such type erasure has runtime costs, and iterating through it will be slower than "raw naked" iteration.  This only matters if you are doing this at a pretty low level in a high performance context, don't let it scare you away.

Comment: In the end, I use enable_if_t to specialize a template function for all the  classes, and forget about defining an abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

C++ only directly supports covariant result type for raw pointers and raw references.

One reason is because with class types, a covariant result could need more space than the caller, knowing only a base class declaration, has set aside for that result.

The templating in the example is not relevant to this issue.

---

In other news:

- You don't want a virtual `operator==` because you don't want runtime checking of the validity of an equality comparision, really you don't.
- `operator++()` and `operator++(int)` are the only two valid signatures, so you can't meaningfully template the argument type.

Comment: @rxu there you can find discussion on something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924754/return-type-covariance-with-smart-pointers?rq=1

Comment: I want the derived class to override that virtual operator== of the base class. May be I should make it a pure virtual member function then.

Comment: @rxu: How do you envison an instance of derived class A comparing itself to an instance of a derived class B so that the result depends on derived class state (i.e., couldn't be specified up in the base class)?